# Insert statement in sqlite android with db.ececSQL statement

Tags: android, sqlite

I just want to insert values into a table if the value provided does not exists in that table, I mean I have provided a column as UNIQUE, so sqlite3 UNIQUE constraint will be broken when that value is tried to input twice, i want an sqlite3 insert statement which helps to do this my code is. I read that INSERT IGNORE is used for this purpose. Can somebody provide me with syntax to do this correctly?
My code is given below.

```
String insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO Bookdetails bookpath,lastchapter VALUES(?,?)";
                    db.execSQL(Query1, new String[] { filepath, none });
```

What is the correct syntax for this query? filepath  and none are string which have values assigned
Also this table Bookdetails has a primarykey field 'id' which is auto increment? will it create any problems when data is inserted like this way?

Comment: `INSERT INTO Bookdetails (bookpath, lastchapter) VALUES(?, ?)` - Mind the parentheses surrounding the fields list!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
INSERT INTO Bookdetails bookpath,lastchapter VALUES(?,?)
```

to

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Bookdetails (bookpath,lastchapter) VALUES(?,?)
```

The `OR IGNORE` causes that when a constraint such as `UNIQUE` is violated, the insert doesn't take place and there won't be an error.

The column names to insert to need to be in `()` parens.

Additionally, you're passing some other query to `execSQL()` than the `insertQuery1` here.

> Also this table Bookdetails has a primarykey field 'id' which is auto increment? will it create any problems when data is inserted like this way?

No, since no insertion takes place.

If you had `INSERT OR REPLACE` instead of the ignore, it would translate to a `DELETE` followed by `INSERT`, generating a new row id in case the id was not specified in the insert itself.

Comment: `03-17 11:48:37.385: E/SQLiteLog(29487): (1) near "INTO": syntax error` this error occured in logcat

Answer (score 2):

String insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO Bookdetails (bookpath,lastchapter) VALUES(?,?)";
                    db.execSQL(Query1, new String[] { filepath, none });

Answer (score 1):

The query is wrong:

```
INSERT INTO Bookdetails bookpath,lastchapter VALUES(?,?)
```

It should be:

```
INSERT INTO Bookdetails (bookpath, lastchapter) VALUES (?, ?)
```

Mind the parentheses surrounding the fields list!